# Git only use this version of file on localhost

Tags: git

I'm using codeigniter and have a git local repo and a remote repo.  When i want to develop on local environment i keep on having to change `database.php` and `config.php` to match local server connect parameters.  Then before i push to remote repo, i have to change the files back so they can connect to hosting server of my website.

This is unproductive. I don't want to create another branch.  Is there a way to use files only for local and when i push these files are ignored?  Git ignore only on local, not remote?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+store+application+password

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3234457/7976758